# "Every two years" auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Wie sagt man "every two years" auf Deutsch?

Zum Beispiel,

> This event takes place every two years.

Ist es

> (a) Diese Veranstaltung findet jede zwei Jahre statt.
>
> (b) Diese Veranstaltung findet jedes zweite Jahr statt.
>
> (c) Diese Veranstaltung findet jedes zweites Jahr statt.

?

Comment: "Diese Veranstaltung findet alle zwei Jahre statt". Deine Version b geht auch.

Comment: Btw, I think that (b) corresponds more closely to the English “every other year”.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(b) *Diese Veranstaltung findet jedes zweite Jahr statt.*

if you want to clarify, you could say
    *Diese Veranstaltung findet, beginnend mit 2013, jedes zweite Jahr statt*.

(d) (as suggested by Emanuel) *Diese Veranstaltung findet alle zwei Jahre statt.*

(e) .. eine *zweijährliche* Veranstaltung [(Example)](http://www.dresden.de/de/08/03/01/c_010.php)would be another option, but this is rarely used (see [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zweij%C3%A4hrlich&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=)) and subject to similar confusion as biannual and biennial.

**Brief summary of frequencies**:

- vierteljährlich (quarterly)
- halbjährlich (every 6 months, semiannually)
- jährlich, alljährlich (annually)
- zweijährlich  (every other year, every two years, biennially) (*zweijährig* would be "lasting two years"--biennial in botanic terms and referring to the age of a person or animal)

Comment: Die Konstruktion "alle zwei Jahre" überrascht mich, weil man in Englisch "all two years" nicht sagen kann. Die Sprachen sind einfach anders!

Comment: In this context, "alle" would be better represented by "every", so  "every two years" would be a rather good match. Compare the Christmas charol "Alle Jahre wieder" which I have found quoted as "Every year again".

Comment: Guter Vergleich, Tatjana. Danke!

Comment: @MikaH. Funny enough, when you would use "all" in English you don't necessarily use "alle" in German. For instance, "All the time" is not translated into "all die Zeit" but "die ganze Zeit". And in those cases you would say "all die Zeit" in German, you again don't go with "all" in English (e.g. "Wo ist all die Zeit geblieben - Where did the time go") ;)

Comment: @TomAu What's wrong with [biannual](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/biannual)? [Semiannual](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/semiannual) seems to be AmE. Does *biannual* in AmE mean *every two years* (*biennial*)?

Comment: @Em1: Biannual means every TWO years. Semi-annual means every HALF year (to match the next). One is the recipricoal of the other.

Comment: @TomAu Well, *bi-* seems [to be ambiguous](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/18544/16833). I think it's pretty fine to stay with *semi-* if this is intended but if *bi-* is used and the context does not clarify, it's sensible to inquire what it's supposed to mean.

Answer (score 9):

(b) is a good choice. The first one in my mind was "Diese Veranstaltung findet alle zwei Jahre statt".

(c) is grammatically wrong and (a) somehow sounds strange to me.